# Search paginated results with jQuery

Tags: jquery, search, jquery-pagination

I have developed a single page app that shows all the entries off a database table. The results are paginated and are presented without refreshing the whole page. The html part of my code is this:

```
<p>Search by Last Name:</p>
  <div class="form-group">  
    <div class="input-group">
        <form method="post">
          <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search by Last Name" class="form-control" />
          <input type="submit" id="submitbtn"/>
        </form>
    </div>  
  </div> 
<div class="table-responsive" id="pagination_data">
</div>
```

The jQuery code is the following:

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){

      load_data();

      function load_data(page,search)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"pagination.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{page:page, search:search},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#pagination_data').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  
      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
           var page = $(this).attr("id");  
           load_data(page);  
      });
      $(document).on('click', '#submitbtn', function(){  
           var page = $(this).attr("id");
           var search = $('#search').val();
           load_data(page,search);  
      });

 });
 </script>
```

I want to be able to search the results without changing to another page. Currently, the pagination is working correctly. I just want to find a way to send the value of #search to the server-side and use it in a query. The way I have used above to send the value of #search is not working.

Comment: Can you reveive value of #search when you click #submitbtn ?

Comment: The value of #search never reaches the server.  If I echo the $_POST["search"], it is empty.

Comment: I don't know php but, If you can reach #search value on js side until post it via ajax so the problem on server side I think.

Comment: If I bypass the Jquery I can access the #search value at server side. I believe that something is wrong with my jquery implementation

Comment: It looks to me like this isn't possible with your current approach. jQuery can only search for elements within the DOM. What you are doing at the moment is inserting a single-page worth of results into the DOM each time you click the pagination link. To search all items, you will need to fetch every single result in `pagination.php` and format the results into separate `<div>`s, then use css to set the `visibility` property of the current page div you want to view

Comment: @Hugo Buff Thank you for your suggestion, it works fine, but it doesn't suit my needs in this case.

Comment: @H.Log. Ah, I misread the question then it seems, apologies. In that case, my questions are: 1. Does your request work when you call it outside of jQuery (curl request)? 2. Is your eventhandler for `#submitbtn` firing?  You might need to use the `submit` event rather than `click` and `preventDefault()` if you intend to use jQuery to send the form (https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: @Hugo Buff I don't understand your no.1 question. I implemented your last suggestion. I deleted the on click handler and replaced it by using the `submit()` method on `<form>` and now IT WORKS !!! I finally have a dynamically loaded table with all the results of my database and I can search them, without _destroying_ the pagination. Thank you very much!

Comment: No prob, I'll post it as an answer in case anyone else has the same issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Submit button is a form input and I don't believe the `click` event is firing. If you change:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitbtn', function(){
```

to

```
$(document).on('submit', '#submitbtn', function(e){
```

You should see the function fire. Note that I added parameter `e` to the anonymous function. This will allow you to perform `e.preventDefault();` inside the function which will stop the default form submission. Typically, this would redirect the browser to the address pointed to in the submit's `action` attribute